# OneToOne relation doesn't generate foreign key

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

I am writing code in Kotlin language with Hibernate Framework.

Tables structure (OneToOne):
[image]

My Entity in BusinessTrip side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_trip")
open class BusinessTripEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    open var id: Long?,

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "businessTrip", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    open var prepaymentDetails: PrepaymentDetailsEntity?
}
```

My Entity in PrepaymentDetails side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prepayment_details")
open class PrepaymentDetailsEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    open var id: Long?,

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_trip_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    open var businessTrip: BusinessTripEntity?
}
```

The problem: When I try to insert record, the foreign key "business_trip_id" is not generated in "prepayment_details" table

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not setting both sides of the relation properly. The mapping you are using is called "bi-directional assosiation". For such relations, you are responsible of setting both sides of the assosiation yourself, hibernate won't do it on your behalf:

```kotlin
val prepayment = PrepaymentDetailsEntity(null, null)
val businessTrip = BusinessTripEntity(null, prepayment)
prepayment.businessTrip = businessTrip
...
repository.save(businessTrip)
```

Comment: Thanks
But how I can implement OneToOne relation using Hibernate?

Comment: Now I am a bit confused. Do you have a problem with autogenerated DB schema or with inserting entities to the DB? Your code looks quite ok.

Comment: I have problem when I insert record. 
Business_trip_id (foreign key) is not generated..

Comment: @FedyaSavchuk Have you tried the code snipped I posted?